# Why does my app crash after i scroll a tableview displaying data from plist?

Tags: ios, xcode, plist, automatic-ref-counting, tableview

I load data to tableview like this:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return [tableData count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [[[tableData objectAtIndex: section] objectForKey: @"Rows"] count];
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [[tableData objectAtIndex: section] objectForKey: @"Title"];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [[[tableData objectAtIndex: indexPath.section] objectForKey: @"Rows"] objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

My viewDidLoad

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.tableData = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile: [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"data" ofType: @"plist"]];
}
```

I use ARC mode

**EDIT**

My plist:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>Title</key>
        <string>Section1</string>
        <key>Rows</key>
        <array>
            <string>Section1 Item1</string>
            <string>Section1 Item2</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>Title</key>
        <string>Section2</string>
        <key>Rows</key>
        <array>
            <string>Section2 Item1</string>
            <string>Section2 Item2</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
</plist>
```

Comment: What's the error displayed on console when app crashes?

Comment: What does it say in the output window?

Comment: I added my plist structure to question

Comment: if it has crashed, there should be more than just `(lldb)` which is the prompt for the debugger

Comment: Go to the Breakpoint Navigator (cmd-6), click the plus in the lower left, Add Exception Breakpoint..., all exceptions.  This may or may not be currently applicable, but is quite useful.

Comment: No Breakpoints http://is.gd/3lCQkg

Comment: When I add -fno-objc-arc to that viewcontroller and put - (void) dealloc
{
  //  [super dealloc];
    self.tableData = nil;

} it works, but when I scroll tableview, my rows dissapear

Answer (score 0):

Do this tableData is NSDictionary:

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];

  self.tableData = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile: [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"data" ofType: @"plist"]];
```

}

Use tableData to feed value in tableView and change tableViewDelegate and datasource accordingly

Comment: tableData as dictionary for tableView and change tableViewDelegate and datasource accordingly

Comment: "change tableViewDelegate and datasource accordingly" change with what? Sorry, I'm a newbie with this.

Answer (score 0):

Do this first in your `didLoad`:

```
NSString *dataStr = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile: [[NSBundle mainBundle]
                                               pathForResource: @"data" ofType: @"plist"]];
```

Add that to an NSDictionary:

```
NSDictionary *dataDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:dataStr];
```

Add the dictionary to an NSArray:

```
NSArray *dataArray = [dataDict allKeys]
```

Finally in:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Populate your table by doing this:

```
 NSString *data = [dataArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
 [[cell textLabel] setText:data];
```